# Angular HTTP ProgressEvent only tracked in HTTPInterceptor and not in actual API call

Tags: angular, file-upload, progress, angular-httpclient, angular9

I have tried tips from several posts. But there is no success. I am trying to trace the progress of file upload but unable to track the progress in actual API call, though I can trace the same in two interceptors that I have added. Strangely if I remove the interceptors still progress events are not reported. Below the code snippet for my API call. We are using Angular 9 and trying to upload file to google bucket via a signed URL. 
I tried a JS XHRRequest to trace the progress events and it works here as well.

```
public upload(file: File, url: string): Observable<any> {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file, file.name);

  const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', url, formData, {
    reportProgress: true,
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', file.type)
  });
  //return this.httpClient.request(req) // <-- I have tried this as well as per documentation
  return this.httpClient
    .put(url, formData, {
       reportProgress: true,
       observe: 'events'
    })
    .pipe(
      tap((event) => {
        console.log(event); //<-- Progress Not reported here.
        return event;
      })
      // catchError(this.handleError(file))
    );
}
```

Progress events are however reported in interceptor. I have two such interceptors to work with both handle Errors. One is HTTPErrorInterceptor and other is AuthErrorInterceptor.
Originally interceptors looks like this:

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<Record<string, string> | null>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (this.authService.isAuthTokenExpired() && error.status === 401) {
          this.authService.loginRedirect();
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
```

But if add tap operator in pipe I can see the progress reported inside same in interceptors only.

```
 tap((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
   if (ev.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
    const percentDone = Math.round((100 * ev.loaded) / ev.total);
    console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
   }
   return of(ev);
}),
```

Honestly I am unable to understand where is the miss and how to propagate this progress events to actual API call. If anyone can point out the mistake from above code that will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a low-level `HttpRequest` for this as `put` method only listens to `Response` event:
https://angular.io/guide/http#tracking-and-showing-request-progress

```js
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/upload/file', file, {
  reportProgress: true
});
// The `HttpClient.request` API produces a raw event stream
// which includes start (sent), progress, and response events.
return this.http.request(req).pipe(
  map(event => this.getEventMessage(event, file)),
  tap(message => this.showProgress(message)),
  last(), // return last (completed) message to caller
  catchError(this.handleError(file))
);
```

Comment: I have tried this. Events are not propagated inside map and tap operators.